# Unable to bind mount volumes in windows containers

Tags: docker

When trying to bind mount a volume in a windows container, I receive an error.

System Info:

```
Windows 10
1709
16299.309

Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
```

Command:

```
 docker run -it -v c:/test:c:/test microsoft/nanoserver
```

Error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container af555741927f43720fa7be719e275c87903392beff24271a109cfed9b2dbd0e2 encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the path specified. 
(0x3) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"af555741927f43720fa7be719e275c87903392beff24271a109cfed9b2dbd0e2","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\af555741927f43720fa7be719e275c87903392beff24271a109cfed9b2dbd0e2","Layers":[{"ID":"dca09312-2011-54d4-91c3-cae59bab50a9","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\fd160da19bc5ff5552185fb8c6229846a8991ef646dbc4ad1e4088ea07a0acfc"},{"ID":"b085e0fe-87fc-58c9-a710-b4ec42281c02","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\3157c88bfaee933226dff3e9d993d5861acf14ed7084ad482b292e4e6d75c078"}],"HostName":"af555741927f","MappedDirectories":[{"HostPath":"c:\\test","ContainerPath":"c:\\test","ReadOnly":false,"BandwidthMaximum":0,"IOPSMaximum":0,"CreateInUtilityVM":false}],"HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["64239aac-c5fd-4114-af21-c9f71255f2e3"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\fd160da19bc5ff5552185fb8c6229846a8991ef646dbc4ad1e4088ea07a0acfc\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}.
```

I have tried all variations of slashes for paths, uninstalling and reinstalling, disabling container features and hyperV then reinstalling and allowing docker to enable the features. Any advice?

Comment: Does the folder exist in the container and on the host? You might need a `mkdir test` in your dockerfile

Comment: has this worked before for you? i encounter something similar albeit using `docker-compose` which used to work up until 18.03. This might related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50087539/875020)

Comment: The long syntax for bind mounting works, but only when I use $(pwd) as the source. I believe these issues are related, but I don't believe the github issue you posted in that issue is related since I am only experiencing this issue with windows containers and not linux containers.

Answer (score 0):

I've got just a hint. I use the git bash on Windows and had also this error message "The system cannot find the path specified". In my case:

1. Using a relative path helped: Not /c/test but ./test
2. I had the local volume share in a Boxcryptor drive + OneDrive. But that does not work!

I know it is a bit of a different thing, but who knows who searches for this error-message.